# Getting random numbers and letters from function instead of a sentence

Tags: c++

Whenever I run the function, the number shows properly meanwhile the `numbercheck()` function shows random numbers. See below:

[image]

```
void numbercheck() 
{
if (number == 918 || number == 920 || number == 928) //Smart or TnT
{
    cout << " Is a Smart or Talk and Text number" << endl;
}

void enterdata(string data, int& data2) 
{
cout << "Please Enter your ";
cout << data.c_str() << endl;
cin >> data2;
}
void input1() 
{
system("cls");
PrintMessage("New Data");
enterdata("Mobile Number", number);
cout << number << numbercheck << endl;
}
```

Comment: you are outputting the address of numbercheck

Comment: With what we have right now, `number` is undefined inside `numbercheck()`. Did you mean to pass it in as a parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are outputting the address of the numbercheck function. Try this:

```
cout << number << numbercheck() << endl;
```

`numbercheck` is however a void function and you can't stream it to cout unless you actually return something from the function that is streamable. This could be an alternative:

```
std::string numbercheck() 
{
    if (number == 918 || number == 920 || number == 928) //Smart or TnT
    {
        return " Is a Smart or Talk and Text number";
    }
    return "";
}
```

Comment: It shows error c2679 binary '<<': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'void' (or there is no acceptable conversion) ConsoleApplication9

Comment: Added explanation for that.

Answer (score -1):

Your function `numbercheck()` is a void function. Modify the line to

`cout<<number<<"-"; 
numbercheck();`

Also i hope your variable number is a global variable, or it will throw an error...

**Edit:** Modify the function `void numbercheck()` to `void numbercheck(int number)`

and call the function from `input1()` using `numbercheck(number);`

Will suggest you to read more about functions and pointers in c++

Comment: This missed the point of the address of the function being printed.

Comment: Well thats mentioned in the comment. And my solution will not print the adress... Do reconsider your downvote, its appalling

Comment: Yes, that was both in the answer I gave and in a comment to the post but it's missing in this proposed answer which is why I don't think it's helpful. Also, `number` must be in the scope of both the functions using it or else the program would not compile, it will not throw an error.